# How to add translation in Fullcalendar 1.6.2?

Tags: migration, fullcalendar, translation

I am using the fullcalendar 1.6.1 and I want translation in it. But this version don't support language translation. So how should i do translation in 1.6.1 version.

Also How to migrate from 1.6.1 to latest version?

Any Help would be appreciated?

Comment: just migrate to new version 2.X and read the docs on official site, it will be difficult in the beginning, but after that it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my application, and the soluction that I've found is to "manually" translate.

You can set a lot of text customization, such as days of the week, header text, months, etc.

Check the documentation http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/text/

Here is how I set my calendar texts. Maybe is not the better way, but I'm pretty sure that will help you.

For automization, you can create a javascript function to change between diferent languages that you pre-stored in a variable

```
$("#teacher_schedule").fullCalendar({
    header: false,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
    timeFormat: 'h:mm',
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    timezoneParam: "America/Sao_Paulo",
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
    columnFormat: "ddd"
});
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!